# reloadData for UITableView changes constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView set up with cells: (no conflicting constraints)
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoeyB.png) and [Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04IcQ.png)

Looks like:
[Pre-refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APTDB.png)

However, whenever I refresh using

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

the constraints seem to change which changes the cell into:
[Post-refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRe5P.png)

Any suggestions as to why this happens?

Code for cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CaptureCell
    let capture = tabBar?.captureArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.capsuleImage.image =  capture?.image
    return cell
}
```

The cell identifier is "cell" and I have CaptureCell which is a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: can you upload a picture of your constraints?

Comment: can u update more code, like CellForIndexPath and Refresh button action?

Comment: @LinhTa uploaded

Comment: @McDonal_11I I added CellForIndexPath, and the Refresh button action is just that one line self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Have you used the hierarchy inspector to find out exactly which constraint was changed? Also, can you copy-paste your console log? Maybe it's already telling you which constraint had a conflict.

Comment: @regina_fallangi I tried using the hierarchy inspector and ended up fixing the size problem. However, now the image is shifted: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brxsa.png) The console log had nothing as well.